# How to check if a component is TEdit type in c++builder?

Tags: c++builder, vcl

How do I check through all the components of a form and verify that components are of type `TEdit`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [dynamic_cast operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Dynamic_cast_%28C%2B%2B_Type_Cast_Operator%29).

Answer (score 0):

Excuse me if I'm wrong, but won't embarcadero automatically add all form-component object pointers to the class definition ( in the header file )..

Such as:

```
class TFormSomeForm : public TForm
{
__published:
    TEdit *SomeEditBox;
    TEdit *AnotherEditBox;
...
}
```

Meaning that you can tell from the header which components are of type TEdit.
Or you can click on the components in the Design View and the Object Inspector will show the type.

Comment: There are plenty of situations where someone might need to dynamically iterate over the controls of a Form or other container, or check the type of the Sender of a common event handler that is assigned to multiple components, etc.  So being able to dynamically determine the class type of a component at runtime does have uses.

Answer (score 0):

My function sets Text property of all edits in a TWinControl and its children.

```
void __fastcall SetEditsText(TWinControl* winControl, UnicodeString editsText)
{    
    for (int c = 0; c < winControl->ControlCount; c++)
    {
        TControl* ctrl = winControl->Controls[c];

        TWinControl* wc = dynamic_cast<TWinControl*>(ctrl);

        // Check if it's grouping component
        if (wc != NULL)
        {
            // Set edits of children
            SetEditsText(wc, editsText);
        }
        else 
        {
            if (ctrl->ClassType() == __classid(TEdit))
            {
                TEdit* ecomp = (TEdit*) ctrl;
                ecomp->Text = editsText;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    SetEditsText(form1, ""); // Clear all edits
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that dynamic_cast can throw a std::bad_cast if the cast is illegal.  You should wrap this code in try/catch.

Comment: dynamic_cast throws exception if you use it on reference, but if you use it on pointer it will return null.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast ("... If the dynamic_cast is used on pointers, the null pointer value of type new_type is returned. If it was used on references, the exception std::bad_cast is thrown ...")